# Finding the number of analytic functions which vanish only on a given set.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S = \{0\}\cup \{\frac{1}{4n+7} : n =1,2\ldots\}$. How to find the number of analytic functions which vanish only on $S$?

Options are

a: $\infty$

b: $0$

c: $1$

d: $2$

Comment: Hint: the zeroes of an analytic function can't be arbitrarily close together.

Comment: @Pedro Then what would be conclusion sir?

Comment: @srijan Are there pairs of points in $S$ which are arbitrarily close together?

Comment: @Pedro Sir i dont think that there are such points which are arbitrarily close to each other . we can always find $\epsilon>0$ such that distance between any two points will be greater than from chosen $\epsilon$.

Comment: @pedro Can you write the answer with little explanation please? I would be very much thankful to you.

Comment: Actually the zeros of an analytic function can be arbitrarily close together, e.g. $\sin(z^2)$.  But the zero set an analytic function whose domain is a connected open subset of the plane cannot have an accumulation point in the domain, unless the function is identically zero.

Comment: @jonas Than you sir for your response. What about this problem sir?

Comment: @srijan: The last sentence of my comment is directly applicable to this problem.

Comment: @jonas Ok sir perhaps i have to think little more.

Comment: @srijan: Have you seen the "[identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)"?  (If you scroll down to "an improvement" you will find stuff about accumulation points.)  That article refers to $2$ analytic functions $f$ and $g$, but the version Pedro and I are alluding to is the special case where $g=0$.  So suppose that you have an analytic function $f$ that is zero on $S$.  Can you find a way to apply the identity theorem to make a conclusion about $f$?  By the way, are your analytic functions assumed to be defined on the entire plane?

Comment: @jonas Thanks for your help sir. Ya our analytic functions assumed to be defined on the entire plane.

Answer (score 3):

First I would like to say that zeroes of analytic function are isolated point.Identity Theorem or In some books uniqueness theorem says that: $f$ be analytic in a domain $D$, If the set of zeroes has a limit point in the domain $D$ then $f\equiv 0$.
In your case $D=\mathbb{C}$ and set of zeroes=$S$(as you have already defined in your question),Notice that $S$ has a limit point namely $0\in S$, so Uniqueness theorem says that only all the analytic function that has zero set as $S$ must be $\equiv 0$ function

Comment: Thanks for your answer. earlier i had solved this question.