# find the number of analytic functions which vanish only on $S$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S = \{0\}\cup\{1\}\cup  \{\frac{1}{4n+7} : n =1,2,\ldots\}$. How to find the number of analytic functions which vanish only on $S$?
as i just modify the given question 
[Finding the number of analytic functions which vanish only on a given set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144496/finding-the-number-of-analytic-functions-which-vanish-only-on-a-given-set)

Options are

a: $\infty$

b: $0$

c: $1$

d: $2$

i think answer will be 1   is its corrects or not ? Pliz tell me

Comment: The answer to the original question applies just as much to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The only function which vanishes on $S$ is the zero function, by the identity theorem, thus there are $0$ functions which vanish *only* on $S$.